# Gradle + Spring Boot can't handle jars with more than 65535 files

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, jar, build.gradle, executable-jar

Using `zip64 true` doesn't create a usable jar file. It can't locate the main class inside that jar, although the file, structure and location of the Manifest.mf are exactly the same as in previous builds that worked.

The real problem is: I don't need sonarqube or gatling in my final build (those are test-related), but AFAIK there is no way to exclude plugins.

The "fatJar"-task is for creating the jar.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
    id "com.github.lkishalmi.gatling" version "0.4.1"
}

// Run in terminal with "gradle sonarqube"
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "asd"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:java-gradle-simple"
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://asd"
        property "sonar.login", "asd"
        property "sonar.password", "asd"
    }
}

// Run in terminal with "gradle gatlingrun", start the application before.
gatling {
    logLevel 'ERROR'
    simulations = {
        include "**/LoginAndSync.scala"
    }
}

group 'asd'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    //zip64 true
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'application.Asd'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.80'
    compile group: 'io.gatling.highcharts', name: 'gatling-charts-highcharts', version: '2.2.3'

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.193'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '4.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

This is the Exception I get:

```
xecution failed for task ':fatJar'.
> archive contains more than 65535 entries.

  To build this archive, please enable the zip64 extension.
  See: https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:zip64
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot why are you creating your own fat-jar? Use the Spring Boot plugin and remove your own fat-jar task.

Comment: @M.Deinum We also run the tests using gradle. All in a docker script. I'm not sure, but I think doing that "on the command line" isn't an easy task?

Comment: What has that to do with using the spring boot plugin. As suggested, remove the fat jar task en use the proper plugins.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did that and it worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to M.Deinum, I did a new approach:

I added spring-boot as plugin in `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}
```

and can now just use `gradle build` in the console, to get a running jar, which can be found in `./build/libs/`.